# Django model get duplicated from foreignkey model

Tags: python, django

I have two models, one to create a title and one to create a vote for this title.

When I create more than one vote on the same title, I get duplicate titles, and I can't figure out why.

Here is my vote model,

```
class Vote(GenericModel):
    """
    Model for vote on a title
    """
    title = models.ForeignKey(Title, blank=True, related_name='votes')

    user = models.ForeignKey(ArtLover, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return _("vote on {}").format(self.title.__str__())
```

and the view to vote:

```
@detail_route(methods=['post'])
def vote(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Create vote for a title
    """
    title = Title.objects.get(text=kwargs.get('text'))
    user = ArtLover.objects.get(id=request.user.id)

    if title.user.id == user.id:
        return Response(
            _("You can't vote for your own title"),
            status=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
        )

    if Vote.objects.filter(title=title, user=user).exists():
        return Response(
            _("Vote already exists"),
            status=status.HTTP_409_CONFLICT
        )

    vote = Vote.objects.create(title=title, user=user)

    return Response({
        'vote': VoteSerializer(vote).data
    }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

If I print the number of title instances after creating the vote, the count is good, no duplicate, so I assume the duplication happens later. Can you point me where/why the duplication happens?

When I delete the vote, the title created by the duplication is deleted as well.

Edit 1 :

I have tried to create a custom manager for the title models to block the duplication, but when the duplication happen while creating a vote, the title manager is not called.

When I compare the origin models instance primary key with the duplication they are the same.

Edit 2:

trying to order the titles fields in artworks serializer

my artworks serializer :

```
class ArtworkDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Detailed serializer for Artwork
    """
    artist = serializers.CharField(source='artist.username', read_only=True)
    titles = TitleSerializer(many=True)
    emotions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Artwork
        fields = ('id', 'file', 'artist', 'index', 'url', 'titles', 'emotions')
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'artist', 'index', 'url', 'titles', 'emotions')
```

my title serializer:

```
class TitleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Serializer for title suggested by user
    """
    votes = VoteSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    user = serializers.CharField(source='user.username', read_only=True)
   artwork = serializers.CharField(source='artwork.url', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Title
        fields = ('id', 'artwork', 'text', 'user', 'votes',)
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'artwork', 'user', 'votes',)
```

my artworks view:

```
class ArtworkView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    View that handle Artwork
    """
    lookup_field = 'url'
    queryset = Artwork.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
        IsArtistOrReadOnly,
    )

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if self.action == 'retrieve':
            return ArtworkDetailSerializer
        return ArtworkSerializer
```

Comment: No titles are created at all in the code you have shown. Why do you think the duplicate is created here?

Comment: Because the title is duplicated when im creating the vote, and in my test this is the code i execute, so i assume django is doing the duplication by himself

Comment: Please show your test code. I can't see how the code above would create any titles, unless you have some signals or overridden methods that you haven't show us.

Comment: Im doing curl request on my view like that: curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/artworks/art1/titles/foo/vote/ -H Authorization: Token 884376b92959b3b17ca366e6147125bc00782b11'. I have no custom manager for creating my objects, i dont use signal

Comment: And you're sure that the request is triggering the `vote` method? What is `GenericModel`? Where are you printing the number of title instances and how?

Comment: Yes im pretty sure, GenericModel is a model who inherite from models.Model with an UUID field as primary key and a created_at, updated_at fields, the models Meta is abstract=True, im printing the instance count before and after vote = Vote.objects.create(title=title, user=user), like that print (Title.objects.all().count())

Comment: The duplication is happening when im creating vote objects through admin to, so the probleme is not coming from the view but from the model ?

Answer (score 1):

When you order by the related field `votes`, this causes Django to do a left outer join. If a title is related to multiple votes, it is returned in the queryset once for each vote.

**Note that saving the votes is not creating duplicates**. You can confirm this by ordering by a different field, and checking the count. As you say in your question, the primary key of the duplicates is the same, so you have not created extra titles in the database, the queryset is just returning the same titles multiple times.

```
Title.objects.order_by('pk').count()
```

To order by the number of votes, you need to annotate the queryset with the number of votes, then order by the annotation:

```
Title.objects.annotate(num_votes=Count('votes')).order_by('num_votes')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, for the ordering this work, but im not doing any request to send back the data, im using serializer, do you know how to apply that ordering at model or serializer level ? (i use nested serializer)

Comment: You haven't shown your serializer, or how you are using it, so I can't say how to set the queryset there. You could create a custom manager and override [`get_queryset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/managers/#modifying-initial-manager-querysets), but that's not a good idea because it will mean you do the annotation for all queries, even when you don't need it.

Comment: I think doing the annotation everywhere could be good for me, i edit my origin post with my serializer if you want to take a look, i tried to add custom queryset to the titles fields to order them with no success. Also i could do a SerializerMethodField but that seems overkill no ?

Comment: Im using it in the basic retrieve method of ModelViewSet

Comment: I'm not sure how you can order the titles included in the `ArtworkDetailSerializer`. You might be better to ask a new question -- ordering the queryset is very different from your original problem.

Comment: Ok no problem, thanks for all the time you spend helping me, i realy appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can try to replace:

`vote = Vote.objects.create(title=title, user=user)`

to

`vote, created = Vote.objects.get_or_create(title=title, user=user)`

Comment: doesnt solve the probleme, its the title who's duplicated not the vote

Answer (score 0):

the probleme was coming from my title models :

```
class Title(GenericModel):
    """
    Model for title suggested by user
    """
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['votes']

    text = models.CharField(_('text'), max_length=255)

    artwork = models.ForeignKey(Artwork, blank=True,    related_name='titles')

    user = models.ForeignKey(ArtLover, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

the ordering in meta was duplicating the model everytime i vote why is this happening? and how im suppose to order my title by the number of vote they get ?